# Using `cout` to View Binary Data on Console

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008, console-application

I'm writing a test application, and I'd like to keep it as simple as possible.  I recall that there is a way to use `cout` to print binary data to the console in ASCII format.  For example:

```
int myVar = 0x1234;
cout << "My variable: 0x" << myVar << endl;
```

Hopefully, this would print to the console something like this:

> My variable: 0x1234

Does anyone know how to properly modify the `ios` (?) flags to print non-readable data to the console in ASCII format?  Thanks.

Comment: Could you be more specific about what "non-readable data" you want to print, and what you mean by "ASCII format"? Your example already prints non-readable data in ASCII format.

Comment: Your question doesn't jibe with your desired output.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You seem to want to print the binary data in hexadecimal format. This can be done using the [hex manipulator](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/manipulators/hex/):

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

// ...

int myVar = 0x1234;
cout << "0x" << hex << myVar;    // 0x1234
```

Note that this only works for integers.

Comment: 1. It works for any integral type (such as `char`, `long`, `unsigned int`, etc), not just `int`s. 2.`using namespace std;` MUST DIE! :P

Comment: @Billy:  re #2 -- bah, humbug.  If you know what you're doing, it's fine.

Comment: If @Jim's question should match the desired output, then this is probably the right answer.

Comment: @Billy: 1: Thanks for the clarification, that's why I put "integers" and not "`int`s" 2. Long live `using namespace std;` ;-)